# Regex end of nth line

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

How can I use regex in sublime to target the end of every third line, so that I can insert a semicolon.

I know I can target/wrap every third line like this:

```
(.*\n){3}
```

And target the end of each line like this: `$`

But how can I target the **END** of every **THIRD** line so that I can insert a semicolon?

Comment: Try `(?m)^.*(?:\R.*){2}\K` to put the cursor at the end of 3rd line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't match the third newline character. Try the following regex:

```
^.*(?:\R.*){2}\K
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lVQWUf/1)

In above regex `\R` means any kind of newline character, `\K` means reset match output and `^` matches at start of each line by default in Sublime Text (so no need for `(?m)`).

Put the cursor at the beginning of file content then search  for the given regex and replace with `;`.